# Neo4j convert string to datetime with merge statement on row import

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following import that uses data from a csv going row by row.

```
// NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/Hourly_Parsed/2019-12-10_00_hourly_parsed_mail_logs.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (b:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,b,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
RETURN a,b
```

I would like to add a datetime field that is in my csv(DateTime) to the `Sender` and `Recipient` nodes.

I have seen a lot on converting strings to date, but it is usually in an `unwind` statement or in the `return` portion.  How can I add a string with datetime and convert to dateformat.

I am looking for a solution and have tried many things like the following but this doesn't work:

```
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, datetime: date(row.DateTime)})
```

My string datetime is in the format:

```
"2019-11-20 10:00:01"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date string is *tantalisingly* close to an ISO8601 date string which Neo4j could directly parse - it's just missing the `T` separator between the date and time components.

One approach then is to just replace the space in the middle of your string with a `T` and let Neo4j parse the date and time:

```
WITH '2019-11-20 10:00:01' AS d
RETURN datetime(replace(d, ' ', 'T'))
```

Another would be to use APOC which can parse that date format directly and give you back a value in milliseconds, from which you can then build a DateTime type:

```
WITH '2019-11-20 10:00:01' AS d
RETURN datetime({ epochmillis: apoc.date.parse(d) })
```

Comment: Thank you @Pablissimo.  I changed my merge to: "MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, datetime: datetime(replace(row.DateTime, ' ', 'T'))})" and it worked my datetime is now of type "DATE_TIME"